# How to write piecewise function code in GAMS?

Tags: gams-math

I am fairly new to GAMS coding and would like to know how can I write code for this fucntion.
[image]

Comment: Epv(t) is the electric quantity of EV at hour t. ch/dch means charge and discharge. 
Set    t     hours     /t1*t24/.

Comment: This is not really a piecewise function problem. You just have to introduce two different constraints. One for t <= 8 and one for t >= 17. I would use two subsets of t for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to code like what you say at first. The problem is, my set is t/t1*t24/. 
If I write Ephev(t)=e=E0phev$(ord(t)=1)+sum(t, Echphev(t-1)-Edchphev(t-1))$(ord(t)<9 and ord(t)>1), there will be error"Set is under control". If I delete the t behind sum, there is also an error.

Comment: (1) Create a subset (2) use the subset to index the equation.

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot!